# Running a SharePoint 2010 solution in SharePoint 2013 - custom PickerDialog not working

Tags: migration

We are currently trying to run a SharePoint 2010 solution in SharePoint 2013 and face the issue that a custom PickerDialog control is not working in the SP2013. In SP2010 it is working perfectly fine.

**ULS-Error:**

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Did anyone ever face the same issue and was able to fix it?

Unfortunately upgrading the solution is not an option for us.

Answer (score 2):

I made 2 empty SharePoint projects. One 2010 and one 2013 and did a compare of the different files.

The only difference i could find was in the csproj file. In the SP 2013 project there is a 15.0 property that was not present in the SP 2010 project.

I added it and reopened the project, and it worked just fine.

You could also change the TargetFramework to 4.5 but i chose to do it in the project properties instead.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to run sp2010  solution in sp2013 how will it run, this is because it has new Dll version that 15 where as in sharepoint 2010 it uses 14
so make sure you are refering to proper dll instead of conversion of project

Comment: You can run a SP 2010 solution in compability mode in SP 2013 (http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/07/22/running-sharepoint-2013-in-2010-mode-and-solution-compatibilitylevel.aspx). This is working except for the custom PickerDialog